# I deployed telegram bot on heroku, but it doesn't works

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, cheerio

My telegram bot works fine on the computer, but when I upload it to heroku, it starts giving out links like http://avito.ru/undefined, when on the computer it gives out links normally like http://avito.ru/2190767024 for example. I'm using cheerio js for parsing. Please help.

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const TelegramBot = require('node-telegram-bot-api');
const express = require('express');
const app     = express();

//`https://www.avito.ru${$('div[data-marker = catalog-serp]>div[data-marker = item]>.iva-item-content-m2FiN>.iva-item-body-NPl6W>.iva-item-titleStep-2bjuh>a').attr("href")}`)

const TOKEN = '192mYixPbnnhLRGU0NqDwvs_4AL0XNACqg';

let URL = 'https://www.avito.ru/simferopol/tovary_dlya_kompyutera?f=ASgBAgECAUT4vA2Y0jQBRcaaDBV7ImZyb20iOjAsInRvIjoyMDAwMH0&geoCoords=44.948314%2C34.100192&radius=25&s=104&user=1';
let URL2 = 'https://www.avito.ru/simferopol/nastolnye_kompyutery?geoCoords=44.948314%2C34.100192&pmax=30000&radius=25&s=104&user=1';
//let URL = 'https://www.avito.ru/simferopol/tovary_dlya_kompyutera?f=ASgBAgECAUT4vA2Y0jQBRcaaDBV7ImZyb20iOjAsInRvIjoyMDAwMH0&s=104&user=1'
const bot = new TelegramBot(TOKEN, {
    polling: true
  });

app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000));

//For avoidong Heroku $PORT error
app.get('/', function(request, response) {
      var result = 'App is running'
      response.send(result);
  }).listen(app.get('port'), function() {
      console.log('App is running, server is listening on port ', app.get('port'));
  });

let result = '';
let result2 ='';





bot.on('text', (msg) =>{
    if ((msg.text == 'пицца') || (msg.text == 'Пицца')){
      bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, `Привет, ${msg.chat.first_name}, сейчас пойдёт куча ссылок с обЪявлениями. Бот проверяет авито каждые 10 секунд.`);
      setInterval(function () {
        needle.get(URL, function(err, res){
            //console.log(res.body);
            if (err) return;
            let $ = cheerio.load(res.body);
            console.log($('div[data-marker = catalog-serp]>div[data-marker = item]'))
            console.log(`https://www.avito.ru/${$('div[data-marker = catalog-serp]>div[data-marker = item]').attr("data-item-id")}`)
            if ((`https://www.avito.ru/${$('div[data-marker = catalog-serp]>div[data-marker = item]').attr("data-item-id")}` !== result) && (`https://www.avito.ru/${$('div[data-marker = catalog-serp]>div[data-marker = item]').attr("data-item-id")}` !== 'https://www.avito.ru/undefined')){
                bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, `https://www.avito.ru/${$('div[data-marker = catalog-serp]>div[data-marker = item]').attr("data-item-id")}`);
                result = `https://www.avito.ru/${$('div[data-marker = catalog-serp]>div[data-marker = item]').attr("data-item-id")}`
            }
            
        });
        // needle.get(URL2, function(err2, res2){
        //   //console.log(res.body);
        //   if (err2) return;
        //   let $ = cheerio.load(res2.body);
        //   console.log(`https://www.avito.ru/${$('div[data-marker = catalog-serp]>div[data-marker = item]').attr("data-item-id")}`)
        //   if ((`https://www.avito.ru/${$('div[data-marker = catalog-serp]>div[data-marker = item]').attr("data-item-id")}` !== result2) && (`https://www.avito.ru/${$('div[data-marker = catalog-serp]>div[data-marker = item]').attr("data-item-id")}` !== 'https://www.avito.ru/undefined')){
        //       bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, `https://www.avito.ru/${$('div[data-marker = catalog-serp]>div[data-marker = item]').attr("data-item-id")}`);
        //       result2 = `https://www.avito.ru/${$('div[data-marker = catalog-serp]>div[data-marker = item]').attr("data-item-id")}`
        //   }
          
      // });
    }, 10000);
    }
    else{
      bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, 'Введите кодовое слово')
    };
});
```

Comment: Please note that you have included your bot token in the above question. In case this is a production token, you should make sure to void it and create a new token.

Comment: Oh thank you I didn't noticed that